# Adding the same callback to two different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, dom-events

While building my jQuery-like library as a learning project,
I got stuck on [handling events](https://learnquery.infinum.co/#event-listeners). I can't figure out why won't
the following code add the same callback to two different events:

```
var eventListener = (function() {
    'use strict';

     return {
         on : function(element, event, callback) {
             element.addEventListener(event, function() {
                                                 callback();
                                             },
                                             false);
               }
     };
    })();
```

This is the part of the [testing code](https://github.com/infinum/learnQuery/blob/master/06.event_listeners/spec/eventListeners.js) (which uses Jasmine) that examines
the feature named in the post title:

```
it('should be able to add the same callback for two different events
to an HTML element'), function() {
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'click', methods.showLove);
    eventListener.on(selectedElement, 'hover', methods.showLove);

    $selectedElement.trigger('click');
    $selectedElement.trigger('hover');

    expect(methods.showLove.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

I just can't figure out where the mistake is.

Comment: Why are your adding a wrapper around `addEventListener()`?

Comment: The fragment looks ok (although a bit unreadable). You should provide more code to replicate, I think the problem is somewhere else.